# Non Polish separable uniformizable complete topological space

Tags: general-topology

Does there exist a non-polish separable uniformisable and complete topological space ?

Comment: Welcome to math SE. Please edit you post to include some of your thoughts.

Comment: This search may answer your question, but if you want discussion it will help to share your motivation for your question: https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=~polish%2BSeparable%2B%24T_%7B3%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7D%7D%24%2BParacompact

Comment: Thank you for the most interesting pi-base reference, but it does not take care of the case of complete uniform spaces.